# Ruby Bignum broken?

Tags: ruby, biginteger, bug-reporting

I am trying to calculate the factorial of large numbers.

```ruby
def fact(n)
  num = 1
  for i in 1..n
     num *= i
  end
  num
end
fact(90000)
```

With Ruby 2.2.0 using the code above, I get the result that ends with a bunch of `0`'s as expected, but with 2.1.1p76, I get a number ending with `...818500998068961280`. Is this a problem with Ruby?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: That last `num` in the ruby code ??

Comment: Ruby uses implicit return, I am returning num. @steenslag

Comment: @Sam-Graham it should be an `end`.

Comment: Oh snap, made the correction, I bow before your catch. @steenslag

Comment: If you are asking just about Ruby, why did you post Clisp code?

Comment: The Lisp code proves it should end in all 0's for those who do not know that part of number theory.

Comment: Using rvm and then using ruby 2.2.1 I get all 0s. However, even reinstalling 2.1.1 I have the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to be an issue with `ruby 2.1.1p76`. I was able to reproduce getting a number ending in `67818500998068961280`. However it does seem to work fine in `2.2.0`.

Comment: Btw. the bug is fixed in [2.1.5](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v2_1_5/ChangeLog) (see the 5th entry about [Bug #10465](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10465)) or newer if using 2.2 isn't an option.